# Using XNA's SamplerState.LinearWrap

Tags: graphics, xna, textures

Has anyone had any luck getting LinearWrap to work with XNA 4.0 on reach profile?

Example...

```
device.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;    

leftVert.TexCoord = new NormalizedShort(0.0f, 0.0f);
rightVert.TexCoord = new NormalizedShort(5.0f, 1.0f);
```

This does not wrap the texture 5 times across the u axis. In fact it renders just as if that 5.0f was a 1.0f.

Another example...

```
leftVert.TexCoord = new NormalizedShort(-5.0f, 0.0f);
rightVert.TexCoord = new NormalizedShort(5.0f, 1.0f);
```

This wraps the texture once, but not 10 times as expected.

So... does anyone know the "rules" for how to use this system?

That is...

Is there a max supported deviation between adjacent coords? 
Do all coords need to be within (-1,1)?
Does the first number have to be negative? 
(And why isn't this documented anywhere Microsoft)

Comment: Marking seems to have the right answer. Also on the Reach profile, you can only wrap textures that are power-of-two sized (ie: 128, 256, 512, etc) ([ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is the NormalizedShort object. "Normalized" usually means a value from -1 to 1. In case of XNA, it seems to be the [same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.packedvector.normalizedshort2.aspx).

Try using Vector2 (floats) as your texture coords instead.